# How can I recall a variable within an agent from another agent? (Anylogic)

Tags: java, anylogic, agent

I need to realize a function which I need to recall within my flowchart (pic below). Body function is reported in the pic, in which I need to recall a variable that is in "magazzini" agent. Body function is written in "tir" agent, so neither is in main. What am I wronging in this script? Thanks so much.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFApy.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMc68.png)

Comment: what is Magazzini... 1 agent or a population? If it's a population, which agent in the population you want to access to? Is this an agent based model or are you using discrete event processes? Do you have a population of magazzini defined in main? A population of tir defined in main?

Comment: @Felipe “magazzini” and “tir” are  both population agent. I need to access a variable (“disponibilita”) within “magazzini” from the agent “tir”.